# iOS find average speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I already have something that shows me my current speed and top speed (max speed in the code below) Now I want to make something that calculates my average speed with core location. How? thanks.

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];
```

Here is the float for top speed

```
   float currentSpeed = [location speed]*2.236936284;
if(currentSpeed - maxSpeed >= 0.01){
    maxSpeed = currentSpeed;
    maxspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", maxSpeed];

}
```

Comment: Keep a list of the current speeds and average them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare variable is your *.m class

```
@implementation your_class
{
    CLLocationDistance _distance;
    CLLocation *_lastLocation;
    NSDate *_startDate;
}
```

In your `init` or `viewDidLoad` method set them to initial values

```
_distance = 0;
_lastLocation = nil;
_startDate = nil;
```

Change `locationUpdate:` to

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];
    if (_startDate == nil) // first update!
    {
        _startDate = location.timestamp;
        _distance = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        _distance += [location distanceFromLocation:_lastLocation];
        _lastLocation = location;
        NSTimeInterval travelTime = [location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];
        if (travelTime > 0)
        {
            double avgSpeed = _distance / travelTime;
            AVGspeedlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", avgSpeed];
            NSLog(@"Average speed %.2f", avgSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

to reset average speed

```
_startDate = nil;
_distance = 0;
```

Comment: How do I put the average speed in a label though?

Comment: Also I want to be able to reset it with a button, how do I do that?

Comment: Thanks, and Quick question, where do I put the declare?

Comment: There are several possibilities. One of them - in updated answer.

Comment: Im getting a crash and it has to do with this: double avgSpeed = _distance / [location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];

Comment: There was an error with that line too before because i had to put a ; at the end of it

Comment: I have updated the answer. If you will still have crash - please post crash message.

Comment: I didn't run it yet but I put in what is up there and there is a warning that says "local declaration of 'time' hides instance variable"

Comment: It seems that you have an instance variable with the same name. It is not a problem but you can rename local variable to avoid this warning. I have renamed it with `travelTime` in my code.

Comment: That fixed the warning! Im going to run it now and if it crashes i will post the crash message

Comment: it crashed, here is the crash message

Comment: 2014-03-08 16:56:34.879 iRide[376:60b] -[CLLocation timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1558f9c0
2014-03-08 16:56:34.884 iRide[376:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CLLocation timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1558f9c0'
*** First throw call stack:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: I think you should initialize `_lastLocation` and `_startDate` with  `nil`. Answer is updated.

Comment: still got a crash but no crash message. there is a green error on the NSTimeIntervial line saying this... Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x715da0d0)

Comment: Sorry, can not help you. Try to put breakpoint at that line and check that both `location` and `_startDate` are valid. Also check that `_startDate` is nil when `locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location` is called first time.

Comment: what does this mean because i just got this: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d5aba0'

Comment: It means that `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` should be called for `NSDate` but instead is called for `NSNumber`. Where do you use it? I have no `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` calls in my code.

Comment: i have a lot of other code in this class, could any of that be affecting it?

Comment: Yes, it could. If you need additional help - please open a new question.

Comment: What type of thing could affect it though?

Answer (score 2):

Remember the first location that you got together with the time. Then calculate

```
CLLocationDistance dist = [location distanceFromLocation:initialLocation];
NSTimeInterval time = [location.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:initialDate];
double averageSpeed = dist/time;
// If you want it in miles per hour:
// double averageSpeed = dist/time * 2.236936284;
```

Comment: How do i put the average speed in a label though?

Comment: Also I want to be able to reset it with a button, how do I do that?

Comment: @msweet168: You put it in the label as you do with the current or maximum speed: `averageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", averageSpeed]`. And you can reset it by resetting `initialLocation` and `initialDate` to the current location and timestamp.

Comment: And how do i declare this and where do i put it?\

Comment: @MartinR The value of `averageSpeed` is in m/s, right?

Comment: @Isuru: Yes: `distanceFromLocation` returns the distance in meters, and the time interval is in seconds.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. So if I were to convert it to km/h, I should simply do `averageSpeed * 3.6`?