# iOS find the average speed in core location

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I want to be able to calculate the average speed with core location. I already have the current speed:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
speedLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [location speed]*2.236936284];
```

And also I want to be able to show it in a label and reset it with a button.

I want it to start averaging when a button is pressed and update the average about every 5 seconds and then stop averaging after another button is pressed.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't accept an answer if "the answers were not good". Edit your earlier question to elicit the answers you looking for.

Comment: Repost of [iOS find average speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22274801/ios-find-average-speed)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  Please try and attempt this yourself and then post about specific problems you are having.  You will get much more specific answers with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As defined](http://math.about.com/od/glossaryofterms/g/Average-Defined.htm): *Average refers to the sum of numbers divided by n*. That is, when dealing with an average, you usually have at least 2 or more observations from which you wish to calculate an average. The average of your current speed is just, well, your current speed divided by one. I'm sure that's not what you are looking for.

You will need to ask yourself for how long time you wish to average. Five seconds? 10 seconds? The shorter the interval (fewer observations), the more sensitive to significant changes your average will be.

Basically what you would do is to store your observations in a mutable collection, eg `NSMutableArray`, and then just sum them up and divide the sum by the array's `count` property, corresponding to the number of observations. Or, as NSHipster has a [great article](http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/) on, you could take advantage of `valueForKeyPath`:

```
NSMutableArray *speedObservations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:n];
...
CGFloat average = [speedObservations valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.floatValue"];
```

Comment: Then you should start collecting speed samples when button A is pressed. When button B is pressed, stop collecting samples and calculate the average of those you have collected.

Comment: how do I do this in code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I would do this differently.

Average speed is distance traveled from a start time to an end time. I would record the user's location when they start asking for average speed, along with the current date. Then I would periodically get a new location reading and calculate distance traveled from the old location to the new location divided by the elapsed time between the current location reading and the first location reading.

Comment: That would be great for a straight path, but you can imagine that if the path is a curve, this average speed proposition could even be lower than the lowest speed reached along the path. That might be what he wants, but in most practical situations, this wouldn't be good (for example, a car race). Even worse if the end location turns out to be the same as the start location - average speed will be 0.

Comment: This is definitely a fine alternative, but as Marcelo points out, it might introduce potential errors. But again, I think it depends on the use case, which is not very clear from the question.

Comment: @MarceloGobetti, good point. We need more info from the OP to determine the best solution